# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Validation failed: Account must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using ruby 2.6 & rails 5.2
User creation in rails console raises

```rb
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Account must exist)
```

I just generated Devise User, so there is no user_controller for now

## models

#### user.rb

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :account
end
```

#### account.rb

```rb
class Account < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users
end
```

## controllers

#### accounts_controller.rb

```rb
class AccountsController < ApplicationContoller
     def new                     
       redirect_to root_path       
       unless current_user.account.nil?
       @account = Account.new       
    end
     def create                   
      @account = Account.new(account_params)          
      if @account.save            
      current_user.account = @account                     
      current_user.save
      redirect_to root_path, success: "Your account has been created!"               
  else                         
      render :new                  
    end                        
  end
........
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With **Rails 5**, `belongs_to` association is required by default. So you should make the account optional.

```
belongs_to :account, optional: true
```

Comment: oddly enough I didn't run into this issue until I upgraded from rails 5.2 to 6.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @demir for that answer, I had been dealing with this problem for 3 days.
Now, I would like to share the way I did to debug this problem.
Step 1:
create a user in the console to undertand the problem:

```
@u=User.new("id"=>"2030","username"=>"kam corner","email"=> "corner@gmail.com","contact"=> "78542036","status"=> "1","password"=> "corneroftiassale","password_confirmation"=> "corneroftiassale")
```

=> #

*Note: i save the new user on variable @u, because i want to user after to save*

2:`irb(main):004:0> @u.save!`

importat: see the errors message.
on my use case,i get:

`User Exists (1.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "corner@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):8
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Level must exist)

` 
step 3: get the error message to debug:

```
irb(main):009:0> @u.save.errors
```

for see the errors
and  @u.errors.details
=> {:level=>[{:error=>:blank}]}

summary:
try to create the new user on console,  use the SAVE! method, when you get errors,
try the @VARIABLE_USE__TO_CREATE_USER.errors.details.
againt thank you @demir